# "TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 8 positional arguments (3 given)" when loading sklearn Pickle

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, cython, pickle

I have a Flask app on pythonanywhere (Python 2.7) that needs to load a pickle file containing a machine learning estimator made with sklearn.

```
    with open("pickle.pkl", 'rb') as f:
    d = pickle.load(f)
```

gives me this error:

```
2016-01-06 01:20:15,469 :Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/znagler/mysite/flask_app.py", line 29, in index
    d = pickle.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1133, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
  File "_tree.pyx", line 1282, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.__cinit__ (sklearn/tree/_tree.c:10342)
TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 8 positional arguments (3 given)positional arguments (3 given)
```

I've tried using joblib and other versions of Python but I always get some error, and this error to be the closest to success.  If anyone has ever made a Flask API that uses an sklearn estimator in a pickle file, would be grateful for assistance.

Comment: Seems like there's a bug in `pickle` ? perhaps there's a version incompatibility

Comment: Are you using the same versions of everything on both the machine where you generated the file containing the estimator and on PythonAnywhere?  (Use pip show to check)

Comment: Please post the full error traceback!

Comment: You need to post the object you are pickling.  However, it looks like from the  `__cinit__` that it's a `cython`-related class that is failing… which is expected from `pickle` unless there's a `__reduce__` method registered to the class… or you are using `dill` or `cloudpickle`, which give you your best chances to pickle any given object.  FYI, `sklearn` uses `joblib`, which uses `cloudpickle` and/or `dill`.

Comment: Added the full traceback.  I do believe it to be a Pickle version error.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to change versions of things on Pythonanywhere.  Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using different versions of sklearn. I.e the version of sklearn that you used to make the model is not the same version installed on the machine that is used to unpickle the model.

I had this exact problem: my local machine was training and pickling random forests using sklearn 0.18 (dev);  I had an ec2 instance running sklearn 0.17 (where I was outputting predictions from the unpickled random forest);

>

```
>> foo_predictor = pickle.load(open('rF_REVENUENext_version2.pkl', 'rb'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1133, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
  File "_tree.pyx", line 1282, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.__cinit__ (sklearn/tree/_tree.c:10342)
TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 8 positional arguments (3 given)
```