# Cannot read pickle file in Cloud Run App. TypeError: __cinit__() takes at least 2 positional arguments

Tags: python, pickle

I have a Fast API application that I deployed to GCP Cloud Run. It's been working fine until yesterday and I genuinely don't know what went wrong. The issue seems to start at this line when I read in a `.pkl` file

`model = pickle.load(open(os.path.join('models', 'appartementen.pkl'), 'rb'))`

The traceback:

```
    File "pandas/_libs/internals.pyx", line 572, in pandas._libs.internals.BlockManager.__cinit__: TypeError: __cinit__() takes at least 2 positional arguments (0 given) at <module> (/app/src/api/util.py:25)
at <module> (/app/src/api/main.py:8) at
    _call_with_frames_removed (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:219) at exec_module (<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:728) 
at _load_unlocked (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:677) 
at _find_and_load_unlocked (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:967) 
at _find_and_load (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:983) 
at _gcd_import (<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006) 
at import_module (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py:127) 
at import_app (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py:358) at load_wsgiapp (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:39) 
at load (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:49) 
at wsgi (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py:67) 
at load_wsgi (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:144) 
at init_process (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py:119) 
at spawn_worker (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:583)
```

Note that when I deploy this application locally, everything went fine.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
COPY src ./src/
COPY models ./models/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY setup.py ./
CMD exec gunicorn src.api.main:app
```

How I deploy to Cloud Run:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/project-id/api --timeout=3600

gcloud run deploy api --image gcr.io/project-id/api --platform managed --project=project-id --region=europe-west4
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
fastapi==0.63.0
google-cloud-bigquery[bqstorage,pandas]==1.24.0
sentry_sdk==1.0.0
xgboost==1.3.3
scikit-learn==0.23.1
shap==0.39.0
matplotlib==3.4.1
```

I tried using the same version of `scikit-learn` according to [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569664/typeerror-cinit-takes-exactly-8-positional-arguments-3-given-when-loa) but the issue remains.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42345) with pandas 1.3.0, and is [fixed](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/42394) with [pandas 1.3.1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases/tag/v1.3.1).

As a workaround, replace `pickle.load` with [`pandas.read_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html).

Comment: thanks! does the job nicely without having to mess around with pandas-versions

Comment: Encountered this bug when I ran `poetry update` which updated pandas 1.2.5 to pandas 1.3.0. The pickle was created using 'wb' mode, and using pandas.read_pickle() was able to read it, even though pickle.load() was not.

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into this same issue when building a new container today. Unsure of the *exact* cause at the moment (likely an incompatibility between the pickled object's `pandas` version and the container's `pandas` version), but reverting the `pandas` version worked for me. The pickle was built with `1.2.5`, and the container installed `1.3.0`. So:

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.2.5
```